# How do i add a circle as a child to a marker in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to add a starting and ending marker to line segments in my D3.js visualization. The relevant code is as follows:

```
let headMarker = defs.append("marker")
  .attr("id", "markerHead")
  .attr("overflow", "visible")
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", "2.5");

let tailMarker = defs.append("marker")
  .attr("id", "markerTail")
  .attr("markerWidth", 13)
  .attr("markerHeight", 13)
  .attr("refX", 2)
  .attr("refY", 6)
  .attr("orient", "auto")      
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M2,2 L2,11 L10,6 L2,2 z")
    .style("fill", "magenta");
```

This results in the following markup:

```
<marker id="markerHead" overflow="visible"></marker>
<marker id="markerTail" markerWidth="13" markerHeight="13" refX="2" refY="6" orient="auto">
    <path d="M2,2 L2,11 L10,6 L2,2 z" style="fill: magenta;"></path>
</marker>
```

If I change the `circle` to other svg tags like `path`, it works normally.

If I print the selection associated with the circle append, I can see that there is an instance created, and it has a undefined parent field.

Any tips/corrections that can help me here?

I can use a path to draw the circle, but this example comes directly from a SVG book and I'd like to understand it.

Comment: runs without a hitch for me: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GMdPQB

Comment: My defs was appended to a `g` element. I moved it up to my `svg` element and it works now. I'm going to work out a minimal sample and post it as an issue on d3, thx for trying it @ccprog.